# Regular Expressions (Specifically preg_split() PHP)

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-match, preg-split

I'm listing out some dates in my PHP application which results in something like the following:

`April2016May2016June2016` etc.

I'm trying to use `preg_split` to format them like this:

> `array('April 2016', 'May 2016', 'June 2016')`

I used an online Regular Expression editor to determine how to detect for 4 consecutive numbers and here's how far I've gotten:

Note: I am also removing all white space - ideally this would be better if it only removed white space if there were more than 2 spaces i.e. `hello world` would not be altered but `hello  world` would.

`preg_split('/\d\d\d\d/g', preg_replace('!\s+!', '', $sidebar_contents));`

Using the above, I get an error suggesting that the g identifier is not valid assuming because it's not `preg_match_all` - removing the g result in the following:

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried [`'~(\p{L}+)(\d+)~'`](https://regex101.com/r/lG4iV1/1) with `preg_match_all`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve what you want with 1 call to `preg_match_all` and using an `array_map` after:

```
preg_match_all('~(\p{L}+)(\d+)~', "April2016May2016June2016", $m);
$result = array_map(function($k, $v) { return $k . " " . $v; }, $m[1], $m[2]);
print_r($result);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lG4iV1/1) and an [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/UgEfRU).

The pattern means:

- `(\p{L}+)` - match and capture into Group 1 (will be accessible after matching via `$m[1]`) one or more letters
- `(\d+)`  - match and capture into Group 2 (will be accessible after matching via `$m[2]`) one or more digits.

With `array_map`, we just join the values from Group 1 and 2 with a space.

**Alternative**: fill out the resulting array inside a `preg_replace_callback` (just one pass!):

```
$result = array();
preg_replace_callback('~(\p{L}+)(\d+)~', function($m) use (&$result) {
    array_push($result, $m[1] . " " . $m[2]);
}, "April2016May2016June2016");
print_r($result);
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/lnTaGC).

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the space and then split:

```
<?php
$input = "April2016May2016June2016";
var_dump(preg_split('/(?<=\d)(?!\d|$)/i',
  preg_replace('/(?<!\d)(?=\d)/', ' ', $input)));
?>
```

Outputs:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "April 2016"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "May 2016"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "June 2016"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$str = "April2016May2016June2016"; 
preg_match_all("/[a-z]+\\s\\d+/i", preg_replace("/([a-z]+)(\\d+)/i", "$1 $2", $str), $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => April 2016
    [1] => May 2016
    [2] => June 2016
)
```

Comment: Why use 2 regex operations when you can do with just 1?